# My Mega-Menu is not showing on top of the Carousel

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get my mega menu on top of the carousel but it hides behind it. I don't know how to make it show on top.[This is before adding carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO8Hv.png). [This is after adding carousel from bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQrPK.jpg). [Mega Menu css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQNV9.png). [Mega menu Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyenW.png).

Please help.

I tried to see overflow and z-index and tried both of them. I don't know if i am doing it right or not. I want my mega menu to show up on top of the carousel.

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to set the mega menu to position absolute, then set its z-index to +1. This will set the entire bar above out of the stack and move it above the carousel.

The other option is to move the mega menu data higher in the HTML page to give it higher priority. It would help to see the rest of the source code from the HTML index. Tell me how it goes!

Comment: Thank you for the response, mega-menu was already had a position absolute and i tried giving it z-index. It didn't work. 

Other than that mega menu is already on top.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is solved as i have given "z-index:5;" to all the "li" and "ul" element in the navbar. Now it is working.